# Erro no v7 appcompat nos themes v21

Tags: android, android-eclipse, app-compat-v7

Recentemente, fui fazer um *project clean* no meu projeto, e não sei porque não gerou o `R.java`, e meu projeto estava funcionando normalmente.

Então, tive a brilhante ideia de reinstalar o SDK e o Eclipse. E agora estou tendo problemas com a nova *support library* e fico recebendo esses erros no console:

> C:\ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
>
> C:\ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:138:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:overlapAnchor'.
>
> // ....

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Poderia adicionar o seu `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: Verifique no seu `AndroidManifest` se as `Android:minSdkVersion` e `Android:targetSdkVersion` estão de acordo com versão dessa lib que está usando.

Comment: no meu manifest está assim:

        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

Comment: Sugiro que elimine e volte a adicionar a *library v7 AppCompat*. Esta minha [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18429959/2556111) no SOen poderá ajudar.

Comment: já fiz isso e não funciona

Comment: Aparentemente mudando o target em project properties para 21 faz o app funcionar, apenas necessitando de colocar mais algumas coisas nos códigos...

Comment: Coloque a configuração do build.gradle

Comment: não uso android studio, mas já resolvi meu problema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tive o mesmo problema, segui esses passos do Lubni

1. Clique com o botão direito na biblioteca de suporte;
2. Clique em Properties;
3. No lado esquerdo clique em "Android";
4. Selecione do lado direito "Android 5.0 - API 21" e clique em OK (Usei a 4.1.2);
5. Limpe a biblioteca de suporte;

e na mesma janela , em `library`, cliquei `add` e adicionei a `appcompact` e cliquei `applay`.

Answer (score 3):

Tive o mesmo problema e consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

1 - Clique com o botão direito na biblioteca de suporte; 
2 - Clique em Properties; 
3 - No lado esquerdo clique em "Android"; 
4 - Selecione do lado direito "Android 5.0 - API 21" e clique em OK; 
5 - Limpe a biblioteca de suporte;

Feito isso esse erro não apareceu mais.

Abraço.

Comment: Isso resolve, mas me obriga a usar a biblioteca do android 5.0 mas vou marcar essa questão.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive este mesmo problema que você, gastei muitas horas ate conseguir corrigir.
Teste por favor.

Atualize todo o SDK, na atualização *21.0.2 build* também tem atualizações do Google play Services. Atualize tudo.

- Em seu *workspace* delete as pastas *android-support-v7-appcompat* e *google-play-services_lib*.
- Importe novamente estes projetos para o IDE e marque para copiar eles para seu *workspace* novamente.
- No projeto ( *google-play-services_lib* ) execute a ação de *Refresh and Build*.
- No projeto ( *android-support-v7-appcompat* )  marque a *API 5.0* em seguida *Refresh and Build*.
- Em seu projeto, em *Propriedades* →  *Android*, importe as bibliotecas *android-support-v7-appcompat*  e  *google-play-services_lib* então *Refresh e Build*.

Answer (score 0):

Se baixou o Android 5.0 (API 21) recentemente, deve mudar seu target no arquivo `project.properties` para **`target=android-21`**.

Comment: Oi, marcolino, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Fiz um pequeno ajuste na sua resposta para não ficar parecendo um comentário. Na verdade, é legal dar mais detalhes na resposta. O guia [answer] tem mais dicas, e pode [edit] a resposta sempre que precisar.

Comment: Você simplesmente respondeu o que eu mesmo falei -.-

Comment: Cara, não tinha visto seu comentário. ele estava escondido dentro da opção "carregar mais comentários".
o que importa é que você resolveu