# Erros temas API 21

Tags: android

Estou tendo vários erros relacionados aos temas.

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'  São várias linhas.

Instalei 100% o Eclipse novamente, mas nada resolveu.

Devido a estes erros a classe R também não gera. Até mesmo projetos que já tinha finalizado não consigo atualizar.

Estou utilizando o Juno.

Comment: Será que não é uma diplicata? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37437/erro-no-v7-appcompat-nos-themes-v21

Comment: Já fiz tudo que esta no tópico que Wakim mencionou, nada resolve.

Comment: Como está o seu `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.tt.guialojaperfeitabase"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <application