# Como tirar o erro do AppCompat do aplicativo?

Tags: android, android-eclipse

Tive que reinstalar o Eclipse e ao importar meu *app*, ele da um erro de *styles* do `AppCompat`. Eu importei o `AppCompat` e o próprio `AppCompat` dá o mesmo erro. Como posso resolver?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Não é uma duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37437/erro-no-v7-appcompat-nos-themes-v21?

Comment: Olá Guilherme! Poderia fornecer mais informações, como por exemplo, como fez para importar, como está referenciando, trechos de código, ou uma descrição mais completa do erro (o screenshot está cortando a descrição)

Comment: Cara se for projeto abaixo do 4.0, não consegui mais rodar, o eclipse ficou assim de repente, projetos abaixo do 4.0  ele ja gera sem a classe R, veja no diretorio gen, se ta faltando a classe R, criei topico aqui mas sem sucesso, a solução foi trabalhar em projetos superior ao 4.0

Comment: @Guilherme Bueno sua imagem não mostra claramente o erro, mas ainda assim dá pra "dizer" que é esse mesmo erro: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37437/erro-no-v7-appcompat-nos-themes-v21

Comment: Acesse este [link](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library) e siga passo a passo a seção "Adding Support Libraries". Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Sugiro que use o Android Studio, Google vai parar com os Suportes para o eclipse então caso esteja fazendo um projeto grande migre logo para o Android Studio, só uma dica.

Comment: Sugiro que você migre para o android studio já que o google já abandonou o suporte ao eclipse faz anos, AppCompat faz parte da biblioteca de suporte v7 https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages

Answer (score 2):

Eu já passei por esse problema, e foi há pouco tempo. Tentei de tudo,dei uma olhada até mesmo no Youtube.

E acho que não tem como, por isso, acabei migrando para o Android Studio.
Eu acreedito que a ocorrência desses erros seja a falta de suporte. Já que a Google abandonou o Eclipse para o desenvolvimento em Android e optou pelo Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Não importe o appcompat, remove esse appcompat que vc importou.

Crie um novo projeto de Teste e o appcompat irá criar automaticamente.
Depois limpe o projeto.